# Getting a Object Required error message with my vba

Tags: excel, vba

Getting an error with my vba

I'm trying to have the macro loop through a list, and when a row has something other than 0 in column 12, I want it to copy the information in the first column of that row, and paste it onto a different worksheet in the same workbook.

I'm getting the error message on the 'Cells(1, x).Value.Copy' part.

```
Sub filter()
    letter = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B23").Value
    x = 2
    Worksheets("ER Data").Select

    Do While Cells(1, x).Value <> ""

        If Cells(12, x).Value <> 0 Then
            Cells(1, x).Value.Copy
            Sheets("Letter").Select
            Range("B10").Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,_
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,_
                Filename:=Trim(letter), Quality:=xlQualityStandard,_
                IncludeDocProperties:=True,IgnorePrintAreas:=False,OpenAfterPublish:=False

            x = x + 1
        Else
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

I'd like it to copy and paste as desired.

Comment: remove the `.value`

Comment: You have your row and column reversed when calling `Cells`. If you use `Cells(12, 1)` then that's cell A12 and not cell L1. Also, you never switch back to the "ER Data" sheet after copying an entry to the "Letter" sheet

Comment: @barrowc appreciate the catch, that was obviously a big problem I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub filter()
dim letter as long
dim x as long
letter = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B23").Value
x = 2

With Worksheets("ER Data")
    Do While .Cells(1, x).Value <> ""
        If .Cells(12, x).Value <> 0 Then
           Sheets("Letter").Range("B10") = .cells(12,x).value

                 ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Trim(letter), Quality:= xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

        End If
        x = x + 1

    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the syntax, I got a mismatch error though when I ran it. I'll show the syntax that ended up working out for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub filter()

letter = Worksheets("Variables").Range("B23").Value
x = 2

Worksheets("ER Data").Select
Do While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
Worksheets("ER Data").Select
    If Cells(x, 12).Value <> 0 Then
        Cells(x, 1).Copy
        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("B10").Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Trim(letter), 
Quality:= _
   xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

        x = x + 1
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If
    Worksheets("ER Data").Select
Loop
End Sub
```